# execCMD("cd ~/Desktop/Tmp/Server/ && java -javaagent:lib/Agent.jar -cp ./Dachuang/dachuang.jar:testcase test.Bank");

Tags: java, exec

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test{

    public static void execCMD(String cmd){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while((line=  bf.readLine())!=null) {
                result.append(line+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            result.delete(0,result.length()-1).append("无效命令");
        };
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        execCMD("cd ~/Desktop/Tmp/Server/ && java -javaagent:lib/Agent.jar -cp ./Dachuang/dachuang.jar:testcase test.Bank");
    }
}
```

Why I get null result on the console? I mean maybe I cannot execute this method right on some complex commands. I can exec("java --version") etc. some simple commands. I don't know how to pass parameter to this method, my command is [**cd ~/Desktop/Tmp/Server/**] and [**java -javaagent:lib/Agent.jar -cp ./Dachuang/dachuang.jar:testcase test.Bank**].

here is my screen cuts:
[no output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEYZt.png)

Comment: Use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Instead of `cd` use [`directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)). And `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead of `~`. Good luck!

Comment: Can you show me the code? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2):

Java is not a shell. You can use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Instead of `cd` use [`directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)). And `System.getProperty("user.home")` instead of `~`. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop/Tmp/Server/");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().directory(f);
    pb.inheritIO();
    pb.command("java", "-javaagent:lib/Agent.jar",
            "-cp", "./Dachuang/dachuang.jar:testcase", "test.Bank");
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Elliott says:  Java is not a shell.  And it doesn't understand shell command syntax.  When you `exec` (or similar) a string with whitespace in it, Java crudely splits it into an array of Strings, ignoring any shell escapes or quotes.  Then calls `exec(String[])` which treats the first word as command name and the rest as the command's arguments.

If you really want to use shell command syntax (e.g. `&&`), and shell builtin commands (e.g. `cd`), you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
    
    // Uncomment the next line if you want the child shell to inherit
    // this processes stdin, stdout and stderr streams

    // pb.inheritIO();       

    pb.command("/bin/bash", "-c" 
               "cd ~/Desktop/Tmp/Server/ && java -javaagent:lib/Agent.jar " +
               "-cp ./Dachuang/dachuang.jar:testcase test.Bank");
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
}
```

This is actually running an instance of `bash` to run a shell command line.  It should work for any command line.  (You would need to use normal Java string escapes for any backslash or double-quote characters in the command string.  That is because this is a Java string literal ...)

---

Elliott's answer is a more elegant solution for your example, but if the shell command line is more complicated, that approach gets too difficult.